# What legal actions can a minor take against an adult having photos of her

Tags: is-x-legal, minor, photography

A man printed out 400+ pictures of different girls, ages ranging from 15 to 20. From what I could tell most of the pictures were from social media accounts, there were mirror pictures, bikini pictures, pictures of mothers with their newly born babies, pictures of girls in bras and underwear. None of the females know this man or were aware he was printing off pictures of them.

What legal actions can they take against him?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: It would be in Illinois and I’m not sure what all laws would apply to the situation

Comment: Did he have legal access to the pictures (lets say they were public on Facebook)? Did he distribute those pictures to anyone, or did he just keep them for himself?

Comment: What is exactly the problem with him printing the pictures?

Comment: @Jen Somehow I didn't read the question that way. Rather, it seemed along the lines "those girls don't like what he's done and they want to sue him, how can they do it?"

Comment: @jen I think it was a fair clarification to ask for that may well influence the correct legal answer: if it is adversely affecting the subjects then the answer may be different, otherwise there *may* not be standing (in case there is even any cause of action at all to begin with)

Comment: @Jen Maybe the man created some real problems for the girls which are not described in the question. And a good answer would then depend on what those problems exactly are.

Comment: Based on the information provided, the single word answer is "none".  However, these sort of stripped down Qs and As are not particularly useful or informative, and Greendrake is spot on asking for some additional information to deepen the understanding of legal ramifications based on what this man may choose to do later with the photos.  He shouldn't be criticized for asking a question.  (*i.e. is it permissible to harvest copyright free images from social media accounts, consolidate them, and publish them commercially?  A good answer would expand and touch on these sort of issues...*)

Answer (score 4):

The people who took those photos may be able to sue the man for copyright infringement, depending on the terms of use for the social-media sites from which he printed them.

The subjects of those photos likely have no other recourse, as publishing photos of themselves to the Internet effectively eliminates any claim to privacy and leaves the man's conduct largely protected by the First Amendment.

Comment: Almost all social media sites require users to waive copyright protections in some form (sometimes a license) in materials that are posted there. So copyright claims are probably a dead end.